# scala for/yield loop vs java for loop (initial title "recursive value XXX needs type", despite type already stated)

Tags: scala, for-loop, types, iteration, yield

i am new to scala. be gentle. I want to do something very basic using for/yield in scala. What is the equivalent of this code in Java:

```
int somme = 0
for (int i = 1; i < 11 ; i++ ) 
    somme = somme + i
```

in Scala?

```
var somme: Int = 0    
for {
  i <- 1 to 10
  somme = somme  + i
} yield somme
```

the error i get in scala is:

> "recursive value somme needs type"

but the type is defined! it is an Int!

Comment: what exactly you wanna do?

Comment: use a for/yield in scala to make the sum of int from 1 to 10. i want to use for/yield.

Comment: Do you want the result to be a sequence or a single integer? Your Java code only produces a single integer, but your Scala version, if it did work like you want it to, would produce a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` in Scala is syntactic sugar for `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap`, and `withFilter`. It is really not a loop at all.

`for` *without* `yield` is syntactic sugar for `foreach` and thus *roughly* equivalent to a Java "enhanced" `for (var el : collection)` loop.

The equivalent to a Java `for` loop in Scala is actually a `while` loop, since this is the only kind of loop Scala has:

```
var somme = 0
var i = 1

while (i < 11) { 
  somme += i
  i += 1
}
```

Or, alternatively written as tail-recursion:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def doIt(somme: Int = 0, i: Int = 1): Int = 
  if (i < 11) doIt(somme + i, i + 1) else somme

doIt()
//=> res: Int = 55
```

If you really want to use a `for`-comprehension, you need to use the version without `yield` that is equivalent to a Java enhanced `for` loop:

```
var somme = 0
for { i ← 1 to 10 } somme += i
```

This is syntactic sugar for

```
var somme = 0
(1 to 10) foreach { i ⇒ somme += i }
```

which is roughly equivalent to the following Java code:

```
var somme = 0;
for (var i : java.util.stream.IntStream.range(1, 11)) somme += i;
```

Note, however, that this is *not* how you would write the code in Scala (or actually in modern Java either). In Scala, in the *general* case you would use a fold like this:

```
(1 to 10) reduce {_ + _}
//=> res: Int = 55
```

And in this specific case:

```
(1 to 10).sum
//=> res: Int = 55
```

Which is equivalent to how you would write this in modern Java:

```
java.util.stream.IntStream.range(1, 11).reduce((a, b) -> a + b)
```

or

```
java.util.stream.IntStream.range(1, 11).sum()
```

Comment: Your Java Stream examples have an extra close-paren.

Comment: Cut&Paste error from the enhanced-`for` example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use yield. The equivalent might be like this:

```
var somme: Int = 0    

for(i <- 1 to 10 ){
  somme = somme + i
}
```

Comment: I'd strengthen the "you *don't need*" to "you *cannot*", because there is no way to use `for-yield` meaningfully here.

Comment: oh ok. am i missing the point of  "yield" ? "yield" is like "return" . why cant i return the somme after i calculated it in the loop?

Comment: @user3600237 A `for/yield` used on sequence from 1 to 10 would produce a sequence of length 10. But you want the sum, which is a single number. A single number is not a sequence. So you cannot use `for-yield` for that. It's not python, `yield` is in no way "like `return`". If you added a `yield` in the above `for`-loop, it would produce a useless data structure with 10 elements `()`, something like `List((),(),(),(),(),...,())`, which does not carry any meaningful information, and only wastes memory.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Even if it were Python, using `yield` would still produce a sequence.

Comment: @sepp2k Either I don't understand what you mean, or: No, it wouldn't. Consider suspendable generator function `def foo():  for i in range(1, 11): yield i`. Now invoke `sum(foo())`. The `range(1, 11)` is essentially just a tuple with two numbers, it takes constant space. The whole suspended `foo` coroutine also takes constant space. At no point does it create any data structure that takes O(n) space. But `for (i <- 1 to 10) yield { somme += 1}` would indeed create an O(n) data structure.

Comment: @sepp2k And in some sense, `yield` in python is a control-flow construct somewhat related to `return`, whereas in Scala, it's more like syntactic sugar for `map`, `filter` and `flatMap`.

Comment: @Andrey This is getting into semantics, but an iterator is a sequence. Therefore, your `foo` produces a sequence. So does `for (i <- (1 to 10).iterator) yield i`, which is equivalent to your Python.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon [Iterator](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Iterator.html) is not a [sequence](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Seq.html) in the "usual javaesque collection-api sense". Sequence keeps all its elements, so I can access them repeatedly (and every `Seq[Unit]` will waste `O(n)` space, because there is no special implementation of sequences that contain copy of the same element). Iterators do not have to keep their elements. In the case of `(1 to 10).iterator`, this data structure needs `O(1)` space. That's basically all I tried to say...

Comment: @Andrey `1 to 10` is a `Seq` that uses constant space, as is `val x: Stream[Int] = 1#:: x`. At any rate, I was speaking more in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use var in scala as it is mutable.

You can easily do this :

```
  val somme = (1 to 10).sum
```

But if you really want to use var and for comprehension for that:

```
var somme: Int = 0
  for {
    i <- 1 to 10
  } yield {
    somme = somme + i
  }
println(somme)
```

Comment: It's not `(1 to 11)`.

Comment: I have changed.

Comment: Good. But the `yield { () }` in the second code snippet is still strange and misleading. And moreover, second solution uses O(n) space. O(n) time is already bad enough (because the result can be computed by explicit formula in O(1)), but O(n) space is really super-unnecessary...

Comment: thank you for the below explanation of yield @AndreyTyukin